# git bash で pg_dump を実行してもエラー: too many command-line argments

Tags: postgresql, git-bash

Windows10にインストールしたgit bashで以下を実行したのですが、
応答がない状態となってしまいます。

```
pg_dump -c -U xxxx -h xxxx.rds.amazonaws.com -f "C:\Users\xxxx.sql"
```

コマンドプロンプトで同じコマンドを実行するとパスワードを聞かれ無事に実行可能でしたが
git bashではパスワードを聞かれず、応答がない状態です。

何か設定などありますでしょうか？

最終的にshスクリプト内でコマンドを実行したいと考えているため、git bashを使いたいと考えています。

ご指摘いただけると幸いです。

**追記:**

応答が無いではなく、実際には以下のエラーが表示されていました。
誤った情報で申し訳ございません。

```
pg_dump: error: too many command-line argments(first is "-f")
```

Comment: `--password`オプションを付けてパスワードの入力を強制的に促しても、パスワードの問い合わせはないでしょうか？
https://www.postgresql.jp/document/9.2/html/app-pgdump.html

Comment: また、パスワードファイルにパスワードが記載されている状態でコマンドを実行すると、どうなりますか？
https://www.postgresql.jp/docs/9.2/libpq-pgpass.html

Comment: ご意見ありがとうございます。確認したのですが、結果は変わりませんでした。（本文に追記しましたがエラーが出ていました。）

Comment: 参考: [pg_dump: too many command line arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11865596)

Answer (score 2):

入力された文字列はシェルごとに定められたルールで解釈され、プロセスが起動されます。同じ

```
pg_dump -c -U xxxx -h xxxx.rds.amazonaws.com -f "C:\Users\xxxx.sql"
```

を入力した場合でもgit bash（`bash`）とコマンドプロンプト（`cmd.exe`）では解釈結果が異なります。

- `bash`の場合

  - `"`はクオート文字列として解釈される。解釈後は削除される。
  - `\`はエスケープシーケンスとして解釈する。エスケープシーケンスに該当しない`\`は削除される。
  - `pg_dump`に渡される引数は `-c -U xxxx -h xxxx.rds.amazonaws.com -f C:Usersxxxx.sql` のようになる（`\`の後の文字次第）。
- `cmd.exe`の場合

  - `"`はクオート文字列として解釈される。解釈後も残される。
  - `\`は通常の文字列として解釈され特に変換されない。
  - `pg_dump`に渡される引数は `-c -U xxxx -h xxxx.rds.amazonaws.com -f "C:\Users\xxxx.sql"` になる。

`bash`から起動された`pg_dump`としては`-f`で正しいファイル名を受け取っていないため、サーバーに接続したとして実行すべき処理が不明であり、接続処理まで進んでいないと思われます。パスワードが聞かれないのはそのためではないでしょうか？

`cmd.exe`と同じ結果となるように`bash`で実行する場合は

```
pg_dump -c -U xxxx -h xxxx.rds.amazonaws.com -f "\"C:\\Users\\xxxx.sql\""
```

とかになるでしょうか。

---

`pg_dump`が`"`が不要だったり`/`をディレクトリ区切りと認識する場合は

```
pg_dump -c -U xxxx -h xxxx.rds.amazonaws.com -f "C:/Users/xxxx.sql"
```

でも動作するかもしれません。この辺りは実行するプログラム依存であり一概には言えません。

Comment: ご意見ありがとうございます。本文に追記しましたがエラーで-fあたりがおかしいといわれていますので、ご指摘の通りかと思いました。pg_dump -c -U xxxx -h xxxx.rds.amazonaws.com -f "C:/xxxx.sql"、pg_dump -c -U xxxx -h xxxx.rds.amazonaws.com -f "\"C:\\xxxx.sql\""など試しているのですが、いまだうまくいかず…パスのエスケープがまだ誤っているのでしょうか‥さらに試してみます

Comment: @kanko 何か変な文字が混ざっているのでしょう。適当な質問に対しては適当な回答しかできません。一字一句正確に入力したコマンドを掲載し、尚且つ一字一句正確にエラーメッセージを正確に書いていただけないと、正確な回答はできません。